# Repetitive concatenations in conditional SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

The **label** of a client is composed of:

- his title (Miss/Mr/Mrs/Ms),
- his first name,
- his surname.

Its max size has to be 20 characters:

- if the label size is > 20, then the first name is reduced to its initial letter with a dot (Nancy becomes N.),
- if the label size is still > 20, then the whole label is truncated to 20 characters.

I have done this:

```
SELECT
    UPPER(
        CASE WHEN 
            LENGTH(CONCAT(clientTitle, " ", clientFirstname, " ", clientSurname)) > 20
        THEN 
            CONCAT(clientTitle, " ", CONCAT(SUBSTR(clientFirstname, 1, 1), "."), " ", clientSurname)
        ELSE 
            CONCAT(clientTitle, " ", clientFirstname, " ", clientSurname)
        END
    ) AS label
FROM Client
```

It works, but doesn't look too nice to me. The concatenation statement is written 3 times and is made 2 times in any cases. Do you have any idea how I could make this query nicer and more performant?

Comment: If this is _really_ a performance problem, you could store the label as a separate field and use triggers to update it. I find it very unlikely, that this would be noticeably slow, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `case` inside the `concat()`, just for the first name.

```
SELECT upper(concat(c.clientTitle, ' ',
                    (case when length(concat(c.clientTitle, ' ', c.clientFirstname, ' ', c.clientSurname)) > 20
                          then concat(left(c.clientFirstName, 1), '.')
                          else c.clientFirstName
                     end), ' ',
                    c.clientSurname
                   )
            ) AS label
FROM Client c;
```

I also changed the length calculation by removing the two spaces and changing the `20` to `20 - 2` (the formula is meant as a reminder that two spaces are missing).  The use of table aliases also makes the code more readable.

And, I wouldn't worry about the performance of one method versus another.  Operations on short strings are not usually the driver of performance.

EDIT:

If your concern is specifically concatenation, then do multiple calls to length:

```
SELECT upper(concat(c.clientTitle, ' ',
                    (case when length(c.clientTitle) + length(c.clientFirstname) + length(c.client_Surname) > 20 - 2
                          then concat(left(c.clientFirstName, 1), '.')
                          else c.clientFirstName
                     end), ' ',
                    c.clientSurname
                   )
            ) AS label
FROM Client c;
```

However, such micro-optimizations are unlikely to make any difference to your application.

Comment: Thanks! It still does two times the big concatenation, in both `THEN` and `ELSE` cases. In fact, IF the concatenation is `<= 20`, it should be possible to re-use the same concatenated string that has been indicated in the `WHEN` condition. I am trying to do that... It would use 1 concat if `<= 20` and still two concats if `> 20`.